# Legal free NXT-G download

Tags: nxt-g

Where can I get a legal, free copy of NXT-G for mac? 
I lost my disk when I bought my NXT, and I need to get a new program.

Answer (score 5):

LEGO has recenlty made this easier to find:

http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads/software/nxt-software/

Answer (score 0):

Try looking around here: http://service.lego.com/en-us/helptopics/products/themes/mindstorms/mindstorms-nxt/nxt-software-download
Or here: http://service.lego.com/en-us/helptopics/products/themes/mindstorms/mindstorms-ev3